# SQLite manager application with auto-completion

Tags: user-interface, sqlite, ubuntu, autocomplete

I am looking for a free SQLite manager application for Linux with support of auto-completion, similar to RedGate's SQL Prompt.

If it supports more than one type of databases (postgres, mysql) that'd be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat_sqlite/sqlite_feature.html) they even offer a Lite version.

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more specific - I am looking for a free app. Navicat seems to offer code completion only in paid version.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [henplus](http://henplus.sourceforge.net/).  It's a shell written in java and it can connect to many databases via jdbc, including sqlite.  It's also part of the debian/ubuntu distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I was looking for a GUI app.

Answer (score 0):

The ["H2 Console" application of the H2 database engine](http://h2database.com/html/quickstart.html#h2_console) supports auto-completion. It works with all  databases that support the JDBC API. There is at least [one](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) JDBC API available for SQLite.